# How to code multiple (array) data in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

For my banner/slider I change the content with a `if elseif` statement to load specific images and links.
The amount of slider images are variable.
I use 3 links separate from the images and 1 background image.

This is my code now: (2 time change examples)

```
if($epochTime > 1427641200) { // zo 29 maart

// slider images
img1
img2
img3
img4
img5
img6

// seperate links
link1
link2
link3

// background image
imgA

} elseif($epochTime > 1427040000) {  // zo 22 maart

// slider images
img3
img4
img7
img8

// seperate links
link2
link4
link5

// background image
imgB

}
```

Well, when I want to code several weeks forwards with different images, links and background, I have to copy/paste a lot of the same code again and again and adjust the images, links and background for the ones that week.

I like to simplefy this and thought about a (week) array containing the necessary data and parse them with some `foreach` code.

And here it stops for me :-(, I don't know how to set it up.
Please help or advise.
Thanks.

Comment: $aArray = array(); $aArray[] = 'item'; foreach ($aArray AS $key => value) { }

Comment: I know the formulation of 'foreach' (php sites) but the question is how to parse the multiple and seperate data along with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out with a little help:

```
$epochTime = date("U");

$Data = array( // newest add at top here
    array(1427641200, array("img3","img4","img7","img8"), "link2", "link4", "link5", "imgB"), // 29 maart
    array(1427040000, array("img1","img2","img3","img4","img5","img6"), "link1", "link2", "link3", "imgA") // 22 maart
);

foreach ($Data as $Value) {

    if($epochTime > $Value[0]) {

        echo $Value[0]."<br>";
        foreach ($Value[1] as $ValueImgs) { echo $ValueImgs."<br>"; }
        echo $Value[2]."<br>".$Value[3]."<br>".$Value[4]."<br>";
        echo $Value[5];

    }
    break;
}
```